# How to replace numbers in a string with numbers from another list?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text string that contains numbers. Plus, I have a number list. I want to replace the numbers inside the string with numbers from the list in the order of the string and list.

By using a Regex I extracted from the string the existing numbers and passed them to the list as well and now I have a match between the original number and the alternate number. However, it is still unclear how I can find adjustments and make replacements in order.

with this line, I extract the numbers from the given string:

```
    list_of_numbers_in_string = [int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', str)]
```

And now I wonder how it can be used, or another method to get the desired result and from this input:

```
    data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:7;} textStyle {offset:0; length:7; underlined:true;} place {offset:52; length:8;} textStyle {offset:52; length:8; underlined:true;}'
    new_numbers = [24, 0, 12, 0, 12, 58, 14, 58, 14]
```

get this output:

```
    corrected_data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:12;} textStyle {offset:0; length:12; underlined:true;} place {offset:58; length:14;} textStyle {offset:58; length:14; underlined:true;}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is actually incorrect (it is now deleted). `data.replace()` will replace the first occurrence of the number, which is not always the correct one. For example, when you try to replace 8 with 14, it actually replaces 58 with 514.

Here is my solution:

```
import re

data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:7;} textStyle {offset:0; length:7; underlined:true;} place {offset:52; length:8;} textStyle {offset:52; length:8; underlined:true;}'
new_numbers = [24, 0, 12, 0, 12, 58, 14, 58, 14]

offset = 0
for index, match in enumerate(re.finditer('\d+', data)):
    data = data[:match.start() + offset] + str(new_numbers[index]) + data[match.end() + offset:]
    offset += len(str(new_numbers[index])) - match.end() + match.start()
```

Comment: This is perfect! Except that the time complexity is `O(len(new_numbers) * len(data))`. If the time complexity is not an issue, then this is the solution to go with.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly operate on `data` (as a `string`) with one `new number` at a time (i.e. `in a for loop` you do `data = operate on data`), then it is likely that the time complexity will be `O(len(new_numbers) * len(data))`.

One efficient way of doing it in `O(len(data))` time is to operate on `a list of characters`:

```
def replace_numbers(data, new_numbers):
    new_numbers_idx = 0
    data_as_char_list = []

    skip = False

    for data_ch in data:
        if data_ch.isdigit():
            if not skip:
                # When we encounter any number's first digit in data, we will add the new number, and in the next iterations we will skip rest of the digits in data.
                # e.g. data = 'hi123hi', new_numbers = [444], then when we encounter `1` we will add ['4', '4', '4'] and skip the rest of the digits '2' and '3' from data by setting skip = True.
                new_number_as_char_list = list(str(new_numbers[new_numbers_idx]))
                data_as_char_list.extend(new_number_as_char_list)
                new_numbers_idx += 1
                skip = True
        else:
            data_as_char_list.append(data_ch)
            skip = False

    return ''.join(data_as_char_list)


data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:7;} textStyle {offset:0; length:7; underlined:true;} place {offset:52; length:8;} textStyle {offset:52; length:8; underlined:true;}'
new_numbers = [24, 0, 12, 0, 12, 58, 14, 58, 14]
data = replace_numbers(data, new_numbers)

corrected_data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:12;} textStyle {offset:0; length:12; underlined:true;} place {offset:58; length:14;} textStyle {offset:58; length:14; underlined:true;}'
assert data == corrected_data
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative

```
import re

data = 'readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:7;} textStyle {offset:0; length:7; underlined:true;} place {offset:52; length:8;} textStyle {offset:52; length:8; underlined:true;}'
new_numbers = [24, 0, 12, 0, 12, 58, 14, 58, 14]
x = re.findall("\d+", data)
data = data.replace("{","{{").replace("}","}}")
for n in x:
    data = data.replace(n,"{}",1)
data = data.format(*new_numbers)
print(data)
```

> [Out]:
>
> readingOrder {index:24;} person {offset:0; length:12;} textStyle
>   {offset:0; length:12; underlined:true;} place {offset:58; length:14;}
>   textStyle {offset:58; length:14; underlined:true;}